# hline too low in tabu environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabu

I've got a serious issue with my tabu environments. Text in cells is always too high or hline is too low. I have tried vertical alignments in every wy I can think of, but it does not work. I am using Texmaker 4.4.1 and TexLive. I am so confused right know... What am I doing wrong?
It seems like Latex treats digits as capital letters concerning their height. Thats probably the reason why they are nearer to the top line than to the bottom line. Is there any way to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \multicolumn{4}{c}{$Occ[c]$}\\
            \rowfont{\bfseries}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{a} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{c}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{g}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{t}\\
            \hline
             0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
            \hline
             & & & \\
            \hline
             & & &\\
            \hline
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
            \hline
             & & & \\
            \hline
             & & & \\
            \hline
            2 & 1 & 2 & 1\\
            \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table]

Comment: You don't need to use tabu on this example. you are not using any X column so use the standard tabular instead.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please could you edit your question to make it a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` in addition to the snippet provided.

Comment: Sorry it's my first question. It does not change anything if I use tabular instead. In addition, I need to use \rowfont for the bold  a c g t line.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \multicolumn{4}{c}{$Occ[c]$}\\
            \rowfont{\bfseries}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{a} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{c}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{g}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{t}\\
            \hline
             0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
            \hline
             & & & \\
            \hline
             & & &\\
            \hline
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
            \hline
             & & & \\
            \hline
             & & & \\
            \hline
            2 & 1 & 2 & 1\\
            \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much David, this works very well for this table! If I knew it was that easy...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `tabu` doesn't insert struts in cells. You can exploit this and insert your own strut; here I assume that the cells contain numbers, so I define a strut as high as a digit plus the depth of the normal strut, so the net effect will be precise vertical centering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries #1}}
\newcommand{\tablestrut}{%
  \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`0+\dp\strutbox}\strut
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{|>{\tablestrut}c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{$\mathit{Occ}[c]$}\\
\head{a} & \head{c} & \head{g} & \head{t}\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\hline
& & & \\
\hline
& & &\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
& & & \\
\hline
& & & \\
\hline
2 & 1 & 2 & 1\\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]